# firebase-admin error No Firebase app named '[DEFAULT]' exists

Tags: node.js, firebase

With the new firebase-admin for NodeJS I get firebase-admin `error No Firebase app named '" + appName + "' exists` error with old and new credentials and the 2 different styles to initializeApp

```
Error: No Firebase app named '[DEFAULT]' exists.  



    var admin = require("firebase-admin");
    var db = admin.database();
    var ref = db.ref();

    admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert({
        projectId: "projectId",
        clientEmail: "firebase-adminsdk@iam.gserviceaccount.com",
        privateKey: "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEvgIBADANBgkqhuPuR\nDAoyxH9OiC1CaSJ8/GquyVvQGvCcsXQAGh2LX2uSXKzycuDGAoUkb2Nhc4dk0/Nm\nLNudSRHCku2h2df0v7z65YXt\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
    }),
    databaseURL: process.env.DATABASEURL
});
```

node_modules/firebase-
admin/lib/firebase-namespace.js:52:19

Comment: Code or it didn't happen : )

Comment: Your code appears to be calling `database()` *before* you've called `initializeApp`. That will effect the error you've included in your question.

Comment: Thnx @cartant that was it... Stupid me ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const adm = require ('firebase-admin');
adm.initializeApp(func.config().firebase);
```

This is one way of initializing your firebase database doing which you can clear the above error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialise the app **before** you try to reference the db.

Answer (score 0):

#### Initialise the app before database calls

```js
    //Import
    var admin = require("firebase-admin");

    //Initialise Admin SDK 
    admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert({
        projectId: "projectId",
        clientEmail: "firebase-adminsdk@iam.gserviceaccount.com",
        privateKey: "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEvgIBADANBgkqhuPuR\nDAoyxH9OiC1CaSJ8/GquyVvQGvCcsXQAGh2LX2uSXKzycuDGAoUkb2Nhc4dk0/Nm\nLNudSRHCku2h2df0v7z65YXt\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
    }),
    databaseURL: process.env.DATABASEURL
});
```

After this call the database fetch function

```js
//Initialise ADMIN Function from above
admin.initializeApp({});

//Call database Function
var db = admin.database();
var ref = db.ref();
```